# How to Include Cloned CPQ App in Scratch Org Built from Org Shape

Tags: salesforcedx, cpq

I recently started using the Salesforce DX CLI to spin up scratch orgs. I managed to generate a scratch org that mirrors my production Salesforce environment using the shape org feature.

In our production environment there is a CPQ application that was cloned from the CPQ package. We have modified the cloned CPQ app structure with custom objects, fields, flows, etc. I would like to include this structure within my scratch org that I created from production, but I do not know how. Can someone point me in the right direction? My end goal is to create a scratch environment from production that includes this CPQ application.

**NOTE: This question has been asked here before in some form, but many of the answers on the salesforce stackexchange site are several years old and pre-date the final release of the shape feature.**

Thank you ahead of time for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative approach to this issue using Salesforce's DevOps Center Beta. This allowed me to setup pipelines connected to Github repos and branches and easily deploy changes (including those made to CPQ-specific components) through various environments to production. To utilize this feature I recommend this tutorial: [Salesforce DevOps Center](https://sfdclesson.com/2022/07/16/salesforce-devops-center-installation-steps-and-demo/).

Comment: When you said CPQ-specific components, you mean can we deploy CPQ templates as well? Because we just recntly set the Salesforce DevOps Center and I didn't know that we can deploy CPQ components through it